# How to have users set a value for a flag field upon flagging?

Tags: flags

I added a field (**Text list** of options) to my flag.  But, when a user flags the content, they don't get a chance to set the value for the field (the flagging form does not show the field to edit).  Instead, the user has to flag the node, then go to the flag edit page, then set the value, and then re-save the node. Instead, I want the user to set the value of the field upon flag creation.

In other words, I want to use flags like I use nodes. With nodes, when you add a field to a node, that field is shown on the node creation form, and users with permission to add the node can also set the value for the fields on the node.

How do I do this in Flag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the flag admin options more carefully.

On `/admin/structure/flags/manage/MYFLAG`, under **Display options**, choose "Field Entry Form".  This will give users the options to enter flag fields before the flag is saved.